# polymer-cli installation failure on Ubuntu

Tags: polymer-cli

No matter what I try, every time I try to install polymer-cli, it always comes up with a PERMISSION_DENIED error.

```
bradley@gurulaptop:~$ sudo npm -g install polymer-cli
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0: ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend Yarn and Webpack for *new* front-end projects! Yarn's advantage is security and reliability, and Webpack's is support for both CommonJS and AMD projects. Currently there's no migration path but we hope you'll help us figure out one.
npm WARN deprecated @types/assert@0.0.29: See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12826
/usr/bin/polymer -> /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js

> wd@1.2.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd
> node scripts/build-browser-scripts

/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/build'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:877:18)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/wd/scripts/build-browser-scripts.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wd@1.2.0 install: `node scripts/build-browser-scripts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wd@1.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bradley/.npm/_logs/2017-06-06T13_10_23_400Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem and followed @Tim Lundqvist's answer and solved by the following way:

**Step 1:** Create a hidden folder in home. *Commands*:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir .polymer-patch
$ cd .polymer-patch
$ npm install polymer-cli
```

**Step 2:** create symbolic links to make it executables

```
$ sudo ln -s "$(readlink -f ~/.polymer-patch/node_modules/.bin/wd)" /usr/bin/wd
$ sudo ln -s "$(readlink -f ~/.polymer-patch/node_modules/.bin/polymer)" /usr/bin/polymer
$ polymer
```

Now [**polymer CLI**](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/install-2-0) is working for me.

---

### Updated

This issue is `node` and `npm` version related but the following command works good

```
$ sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g polymer-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem installing the package `wd` as root. One way to work around this fact is to do a non global npm install of `polymer-cli` and use the local bin path.

```
$ cd ~
$ npm install polymer-cli
$ ~/node_modules/.bin/polymer --version
1.1.0
```

After which you may either copy all dependencies to `/usr/lib/node_modules` and `/usr/bin/` or create symbolic links to the executables (which may be easier for a singe user system).

```
$ sudo ln -s "$(readlink -f ~/node_modules/.bin/wd)" /usr/bin/wd
$ sudo ln -s "$(readlink -f ~/node_modules/.bin/polymer)" /usr/bin/polymer
```

When the path `/usr/bin/polymer` exists you should be able to use the `polymer` command as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Xubuntu,  this worked

sudo npm install -g polymer-cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Answer (score 1):

I got myself in the same situation. I could not install or update to the latest polymer-cli version (1.2.0). The two previous answers didn't help me at all. My solution was the downgrade of npm. I had installed:

```
node -v: v7.x.x
npm  -v: v5.x.x
```

And that was the real problem.
After downgrading to npm 4.x.x by:

```
 sudo npm install -g npm@4.1.2
```

I was able to install the latest polymer-cli via:

```
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need previous also to uninstall the old wd & polymer-cli unifinished installation:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g wd polymer-cli
sudo rm /usr/bin/polymer
```

That work now for me with the tips of Tim and the same start bug after this clean up

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: [polymer-cli global install error](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/836)

```
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried different things, but what finally helped me was this:

`sudo npm install -g yarn`

(Consider Yarn and Webpack or Parce)